# Two type of authentication - laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

We all know that there is only one `auth.php` where we can declare our model,table,etc.. which will be used for the built-in auth function of L4. Is there a way I can create another auth?

SCENARIO: A typical site has user and an ADMIN PORTAL which has the full control of the site and of course both needs LOGIN. Auth function of L4 is already setup for the user but how about for the admin? I would really love to have the same auth function for admin like what the user has.

Comment: Isn't the admin also a user just with some admin rights?

Comment: yes.but how can I implement the already-filled auth.php if I have a new set of table and model for admin? I want to implement the same auth for my admin like what the user auth has. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with two separate issues authentication and access/permissions.  You would use a single user table to hand authentication/log in regardless of whether it is a standard user or admin user.  You would then want a permissions system to handle determining what the active user is allowed to do.  You could make this as simple as having a `type` column on your user table that you use to determine whether you give the user the admin or regular views.  Or, you could go more advanced and use something like [sentry](http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2) or [authority](https://github.com/machuga/authority).  You could also do some research on RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) if you want to take a stab at it yourself.

Comment: Yeah. That should be my algorithm to this situation. All I though there's a way I can do separate auth for another type of user. actually, after reading some article and the docu of L4, this should be the idea.

Comment: You *can* do two types of authentication (see [Anvard](https://bitbucket.org/atticmedia/anvard), for example), but for your particular situation, it is probably not the right way to go.